# Delphi - Unable to change Function in Excel PivotField

Tags: excel, delphi, com, pivot-table

Delphi 10 / Seattle, Excel 2013.  I am using Delphi to build an Excel plugin.  This plugin will create a Pivot table.  My challenge is setting the specific FUNCTION I want (Count vs Average vs Sum, etc).  If I do NOT set a function, the default (COUNT) is used, and my code works fine, the pivot table is like it should be.  If I try to change the function on a PivotField, then I get an error "Unable to set the Function property of the PivotField class."  In searching the error, I have found 2 common causes. (1) The Pivot table has to have a default version of xlPivotTableVersion15, and (2) the PivotField orientation has to be set to xlDataField.  I have done both, and when moused-over, the IDE shows the Integer values for both, so I know they are defined.

I have tried getting (as opposed to setting) the value of the PivotField.function.  I get a similar error "Unable to get the Function property of the PivotField class".  The column I am wanting to Sum is called '#Clicks'.  The offending line of code is

```
 myPivotTable.PivotFields('#Clicks').function := xlSum;
```

If I comment this line out, my routine runs fine, although I get the default COUNT function, instead of the SUM function that I want.

Any ideas appreciated.  Note that when the line is commented out, and I run the code, I can then go into Excel, and go into the PivotField listings, and change the function from Count to Sum. Here is my full code.

```
procedure  T_ZTemplateForm.TestPivotTable;
var
myPivotCache: OleVariant;
myPivotTable : OleVariant;
myActive_WorkBook : OleVariant;
TabDestination : string;
f1: OleVariant;

begin
  // Add the new Sheet
  XLApp.Connect; // XLApp is a global variable, pointing to the Excel instance
  myActive_WorkBook := XLApp.ActiveWorkbook;
  XLApp.Worksheets.Add(EmptyParam, EmptyParam,1, xlWorksheet, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT );

  // Get a handle to the new sheet and set the Sheet Name
  sheet_graph1 := XLApp.ActiveSheet;
  sheet_graph1.Name := 'Graph1';

  // Create a Pivot Cache
  myPivotCache := myActive_WorkBook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase,'Raw Data!R1C1:R1048576C36',xlPivotTableVersion15);

  // Create a Pivot table within the PivotCache
  TabDestination := 'Graph1!R3C1';
  myPivotTable := myPivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TabDestination, 'PivotTable1',xlPivotTableVersion15);

   // Now start adding the fields...
   f1 :=  myPivotTable.PivotFields('Fiscal Quarter');
   f1.Orientation := xlRowField;
   f1.Position := 1;

   myPivotTable.PivotFields('#Clicks').orientation := xlDataField;
  // myPivotTable.PivotFields('#Clicks').function := xlSum;

end;
```

Comment: How **exactly** are you creating your '#Clicks' PivotField?

Comment: @@MartynA - #Clicks is the name/header of one of the columns of data on the Raw Data sheet.  Each column of that sheet is accessible in the PivotCache/PivotTable (at least as I understand it).

Comment: Additional Info:  When I look in the Excel_TLB file, it says that PivotTable.Function is changed to 'PivotTable.Function_ '   Unfortunately that does not help me, but it may be a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** I can reproduce your problems with Set_Function and GetFunction using Seattle and Excel 2007, so please disregard the original version of my answer.

However, I have found a way to use CreateDataField to create a PivotField with a `Function` of xlCount, and it is very simple.

Given local variables

```
var
  DataField : OleVariant;
  Value : OleVariant;
```

the following code executes without complaint and correctly

```
  Value := xlCount;
  DataField := DestinationSheet.PivotTables('APivotTable').AddDataField(
    vPivotField,
    'Count',
    Value
    );
```

whereas

```
  DataField := DestinationSheet.PivotTables('APivotTable').AddDataField(
    vPivotField,
    'Count',
    xlCount
    );
```

fails with the error message you quoted.  So I can only guess that when `AddDataField` is called with the "raw" value `xlCount`, the Function_ argument the compiler generates is somehow incorrectly "packaged" whereas when the argument is an OleVariant containing the `xlCount` value, it is correctly packaged.

I'll leave you to try out the other `XlConsolidationFunction` values - I've had enough of this problem for now!

Original Answer: <s>Judging by my experiments, you can change the Excel 'function' you want to use without specifying the final parameter (in your case xlSum) of `AddDataField`.  In fact with Seattle and Excel2007, I can't get `AddDataField` to execute without getting a 'The parameter is incorrect' exception for *any* value of the final, 'function' parameter.</s>

I have a WorkBook with a table of Company names, dividend payment dates and amounts.  The table headers are Company, PaymentDate and Amount.

The code below works for me and allows me to choose the function to be applied to the Amount column, simply by specifying the name of the function as the `Caption` parameter of AddDataField.  I've used late binding mainly for ease of set-up, and so that I can easily omit arguments for parameters I don't want to specify.

Code:

```
procedure  TForm1.TestPivotTable;
var
  vXLApp : OleVariant;
  PivotCache: OleVariant;
  PivotTable : OleVariant;
  ActiveWorkBook : OleVariant;
  DestinationSheet : OleVariant;
  FN : String;
  Destination : OleVariant;
  PivotField : OleVariant;
  DataField : OleVariant;
begin
  vXLApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  vXLApp.Visible := True;

  FN := 'D:\aaad7\officeauto\MAPivot.xlsm';
  Assert(FileExists(FN));
  vXLApp.Workbooks.Open(FN);
  ActiveWorkBook := vXLApp.ActiveWorkbook;

  PivotCache := ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType := xlDatabase,
    SourceData := 'Table1', //'R2C1R30C3',
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion2000);

  DestinationSheet := ActiveWorkBook.Sheets['Sheet3'];
  Destination := DestinationSheet.Name + '!R3C1';
  PivotTable := PivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination := Destination,
   TableName := 'APivotTable'
   );

  DestinationSheet.Select;
  DestinationSheet.Cells[3, 1].Select;
  DestinationSheet.PivotTables('APivotTable').PivotFields('Company').Orientation := xlRowField;
  DestinationSheet.PivotTables('APivotTable').PivotFields('Company').Position := 1;

  DestinationSheet.PivotTables('APivotTable').PivotFields('PayDate').Orientation := xlRowField;
  DestinationSheet.PivotTables('APivotTable').PivotFields('PayDate').Position := 2;

  DestinationSheet.PivotTables('APivotTable').PivotFields('Amount').Orientation := xlRowField;
  DestinationSheet.PivotTables('APivotTable').PivotFields('Amount').Position := 3;

  PivotField := DestinationSheet.PivotTables('APivotTable').PivotFields('Amount');
  DataField := DestinationSheet.PivotTables('APivotTable').AddDataField(
    Field := PivotField,
    Caption := 'Sum');
end;
```

Comment: @@MartynA, I tried your code, and while it works, it doesn't solve the issue.  You set your default PivotTableVersion to xlPivotTableVersion2000. The default function in this version appears to be Sum, so that is what you get when you don't specify anything else..  Unfortunately, in your example,SUM is all I can get, I can't then choose Count, or any of the other functions.  Note:  When I look in the Excel_TLB file, it says that PivotTable.Function is changed to PivotTable.Function_    Unfortunately that does not help me, but it may be a clue.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: a) Are you using one of the Excel type library imports that are supplied with Seattle, and if so, which one or have you created your own by going to `Component | Import Component` in the IDE? I'm using one I generated that way from the Excel 2007 which I have installed.  I used the Version2000 simply as a lowest common denominator.  b)  I don't think there is any significance to PivotTable.Function being renamed - Delphi's type-library importer frequently does that to avoid names in the .Pas file colliding with Delphi reserved words and such like, including 'Application'.

Comment: @@MartynA - I generated my own from Import in the IDE.  It is called Excel_TLB, and is based off of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\EXCEL.EXE (Which is Excel 2013 as that is the version I have installed)